# Android List Adapter inflates the same View over and over

Tags: android, android-listview, baseadapter

In my sudoku app I am trying to make the List Adapter inflate a custom preview view for each list item/puzzle, but for some reason the adapter always inflates the same custom view over and over. Any suggestions?

[Screenshot of Problem](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxdduvOw1kDYM0hPNmpBUTZmaEk/view?usp=sharing)

**Here is my List Adapter Class**

```
package com.example.czhou.myapplication2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.File;

public class SudokuListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    String data[];
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public SudokuListAdapter(Context context, String[] data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        if (vi == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        TextView text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.date);
        text.setText(data[position]);
        System.out.println("pos: " + position);

        SudokuPreviewView view = (SudokuPreviewView) vi.findViewById(R.id.preview);
        view.setData("puzzle" + data[position]);
        return vi;
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();


    }

    public void setData(String[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

**Here is the List Activity**

```
package com.example.czhou.myapplication2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentProviderOperation;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.RotateAnimation;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Created by czhou on 1/18/2015.
 */
public class SudokuListActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public static String[] fileNames;
    public SudokuListAdapter mAdapter;
    public static File[] files;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Context c = this;

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);




        files = c.getFilesDir().listFiles();
        fileNames = new String[files.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            fileNames[i] = files[i].getName().substring(6,files[i].getName().length());
        }


        mAdapter = new SudokuListAdapter(this, fileNames);
        lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SudokuListActivity.this,SudokuGameActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("FILE","puzzle" + fileNames[position]);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_list_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Context c = this;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.add:
                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yy hh:mm:ss a");
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

                String fn = "puzzle" + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
                SudokuGen sg = new SudokuGen();
                CellField cf = sg.generate();

                FileOutputStream outputStream;

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                        if (cf.field[i][j].isEditable) {
                            sb.append(",");
                        } else {
                            sb.append(".");
                        }
                        if (cf.field[i][j].isWrong) {
                            sb.append("!");
                        } else {
                            sb.append(".");
                        }

                        sb.append(cf.field[i][j].getValue());
                    }
                }

                try {

                    outputStream = openFileOutput(fn, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    outputStream.write(sb.toString().getBytes());
                    outputStream.close();
                    System.out.println("Saving... ");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Intent intent = new Intent(this, SudokuGameActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("FILE",fn);
                startActivity(intent);
            break;
            default:

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        System.out.println("restarting.. ");
        Context c = this;

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);




        files = c.getFilesDir().listFiles();
        fileNames = new String[files.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            fileNames[i] = files[i].getName().substring(6,files[i].getName().length());
        }


        mAdapter = new SudokuListAdapter(this, fileNames);
        lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SudokuListActivity.this,SudokuGameActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("FILE","puzzle" + fileNames[position]);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        super.onRestart();
    }


}
```

**Here is my Preview View Class**

```
package com.example.czhou.myapplication2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by czhou on 1/19/2015.
 */
public class SudokuPreviewView extends View{
        public float mCellSize = 0;
        public boolean mOrientationLandscape;
        public float mTextSize;

        private Paint mTextColor;
        private Paint mTextColorBold;
        private Paint mLineColor;
        private Paint mRect;
        private Paint mRectSecondary;
        private Paint mGridLine;
        private Paint mSelectedCellColor;
        private Paint mErrorCellColor;
        private DisplayMetrics displayMetrics;
        private float x;
        private float y;
        private int[] mSelectedCellCordPair;
        private ArrayList<Integer> mErrorCellPairs;
        public static CellField cf;
        private static String mFileName;
        public static Cell[][] cells;
        private Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        Rect mTextBounds;


        private float dpHeight;
        private float dpWidth;

        public SudokuPreviewView(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {

            super(c, attrs);
            setWillNotDraw(false);

            TypedArray a = c.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                    attrs,
                    R.styleable.SudokuPreviewView,
                    0, 0);
            mCellSize = a.getDimension(R.styleable.SudokuPreviewView_mCell,30f);
            mOrientationLandscape = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.SudokuPreviewView_mOrientationPortrait, false);
            mTextSize = a.getDimension(R.styleable.SudokuPreviewView_mTextSize, 5f);

            a.recycle();
            init();
        }

        private void init() {
            cf = new CellField();
            cells = new Cell[9][9];

            StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

            try {


                Context c = getContext();
                File inputStream = c.getFileStreamPath(mFileName);


                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    text.append(line);
                }
                br.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                cells = cf.field;
            }

            if (text.length() == 243) {

                for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                        Cell cell = new Cell();

                        int index = 0;

                        if (text.substring(index, index + 3).startsWith(",!")) {
                            cell.setValue(Integer.parseInt(text.substring(index + 2, index + 3)));
                            cell.isEditable = true;
                            cell.isWrong = true;
                        } else if (text.substring(index, index + 3).startsWith(",.")) {
                            cell.setValue(Integer.parseInt(text.substring(index + 2, index + 3)));
                            cell.isEditable = true;
                        } else if (text.substring(index, index + 3).startsWith("..")) {
                            cell.setValue(Integer.parseInt(text.substring(index + 2, index + 3)));
                        }


                        cells[i][j] = cell;
                        text.delete(index, index + 3);

                    }
                }
            }



            mTextBounds = new Rect();
            displayMetrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            dpHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels / displayMetrics.density;
            dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;

            mLineColor = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            mLineColor.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.material_blue_grey_900));
            mLineColor.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mLineColor.setStrokeWidth(toDP(1f));

            mRect = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            mRect.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.background_material_light));

            mRectSecondary = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            mRectSecondary.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);

            mSelectedCellColor = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            mSelectedCellColor.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            mSelectedCellColor.setAlpha(100);
            mSelectedCellColor.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

            mGridLine = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            mGridLine.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.material_blue_grey_950));
            mGridLine.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            mGridLine.setStrokeWidth(toDP(3f));

            Paint.FontMetrics fm = new Paint.FontMetrics();
            mTextColor = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            mTextColor.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            mTextColor.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            mTextColor.setTextSize(mTextSize);
            mTextColor.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
            mTextColor.getFontMetrics(fm);

            mTextColorBold = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            mTextColorBold.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
            mTextColorBold.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            mTextColorBold.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            mTextColorBold.setTextSize(mTextSize);
            mTextColorBold.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

            mTextColorBold.getFontMetrics(fm);

            mErrorCellColor = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            mErrorCellColor.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            mErrorCellColor.setColor(Color.RED);
            mErrorCellColor.setAlpha(80);
            mErrorCellPairs = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
                setMeasuredDimension((int) mCellSize * 9, (int) mCellSize * 9);

        }

        public void onDraw(Canvas c) {
            super.onDraw(c);

            for (int i = 0; i < mCellSize * 9; i += mCellSize) {
                for (int j = 0; j < mCellSize * 9; j += mCellSize) {
                    String s = String.valueOf(cells[(int) (i / mCellSize)][(int) (j / mCellSize)].getValue());

                    // check for wrong cells and highlight them
//                if (j >= mCellSize * 3 && j < mCellSize * 6 && i >= 0 && i < mCellSize * 3 ||
//                        j >= mCellSize * 3 && j < mCellSize * 6 && i >= mCellSize * 6 && i < mCellSize * 9 ||
//                        i >= mCellSize * 3 && i < mCellSize * 6 && j >= 0 && j < mCellSize * 3 ||
//                        i >= mCellSize * 3 && i < mCellSize * 6 && j >= mCellSize * 6 && j < mCellSize * 9) {
//
                    if (!cells[(int) (i / mCellSize)][(int) (j / mCellSize)].isEditable) {
                        c.drawRect(j, i, j + mCellSize, i + mCellSize, mRectSecondary);
                        c.drawRect(j, i, j + mCellSize, i + mCellSize, mLineColor);
                    } else {
//                } else {
                        c.drawRect(j, i, j + mCellSize, i + mCellSize, mLineColor);
                    }
//                }

                    mTextColor.getTextBounds(s, 0, s.length(), mTextBounds);
                    float mTextHeight = mTextBounds.height();
                    float mTextWidth = mTextBounds.width();
                    if (!s.equals("0")) {
                        if (!cells[(int) (i / mCellSize)][(int) (j / mCellSize)].isEditable) {
                            c.drawText(s, j + mCellSize / 2, (i + mTextHeight) + ((mCellSize / 2) - (mTextHeight / 2)), mTextColorBold);
                        } else {
                            c.drawText(s, j + mCellSize / 2, (i + mTextHeight) + ((mCellSize / 2) - (mTextHeight / 2)), mTextColor);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            c.drawRect(0, 0, mCellSize * 9, mCellSize * 9, mGridLine);
            c.drawLine(mCellSize * 3, 0, mCellSize * 3, mCellSize * 9, mGridLine);
            c.drawLine(mCellSize * 6, 0, mCellSize * 6, mCellSize * 9, mGridLine);

            c.drawRect(0, mCellSize * 3, mCellSize * 9, mCellSize * 6, mGridLine);

            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {

                    if (cells[i][j].isWrong) {
                        Cell wrong = cells[i][j];
                        if (wrong.getValue() == 0) {
                            wrong.isWrong = false;
                        } else {
                            if (wrong.errorCords.isEmpty()) {

                                for (int k = 0; k < 9; k++) {
                                    if (cells[k][j].getValue() == wrong.getValue() && k != i) {
                                        wrong.errorCords.add(j);
                                        wrong.errorCords.add(k);
                                    }
                                }
                                for (int k = 0; k < 9; k++) {
                                    if (cells[i][k].getValue() == wrong.getValue() && k != j) {
                                        wrong.errorCords.add(k);
                                        wrong.errorCords.add(i);
                                    }
                                }
                                cf.field = cells;
                                wrong.errorCords.addAll(cf.getSectorCords(i, j, wrong.getValue()));
                            }
                            for (int k = 0; k < wrong.errorCords.size(); k += 2) {
                                c.drawRect(wrong.errorCords.get(k) * mCellSize, wrong.errorCords.get(k + 1) * mCellSize, (wrong.errorCords.get(k) * mCellSize) + mCellSize, (wrong.errorCords.get(k + 1) * mCellSize) + mCellSize, mErrorCellColor);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    //               }

                }
            }


            if (mSelectedCellCordPair != null) {
                x = mSelectedCellCordPair[0];
                y = mSelectedCellCordPair[1];

                if (mSelectedCellCordPair[0] < 9 && mSelectedCellCordPair[1] < 9) {


                    if (x == 0 || y == 0) {
                        if (x == 0 && y == 0) {
                            c.drawRect(x, y, mCellSize, mCellSize, mSelectedCellColor);
                        } else if (x == 0) {
                            c.drawRect(x, y * mCellSize, (x + 1) * mCellSize, (y + 1) * mCellSize, mSelectedCellColor);
                        } else {
                            c.drawRect(x * mCellSize, y, (x + 1) * mCellSize, (y + 1) * mCellSize, mSelectedCellColor);
                        }
                    } else {
                        c.drawRect(x * mCellSize, y * mCellSize, (x + 1) * mCellSize, (y + 1) * mCellSize, mSelectedCellColor);
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        private float toDP(float dp) {
            DisplayMetrics metrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            float fpixels = metrics.density * dp;
            int pixels = (int) (fpixels + 0.5f);
            return pixels;
        }

        private float toPixels(float dp) {
            Resources r = getResources();
            float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, r.getDisplayMetrics());
            return px;
        }

        public void setData (String FileName){
            mFileName = FileName;
            System.out.println(FileName);
            init();
            invalidate();
        }


    }
```

**Here is the row.xml**

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <com.example.czhou.myapplication2.SudokuPreviewView
            android:layout_width="203dp"
            android:layout_height="258dp"
            android:id="@+id/preview"
            custom:mCell="15dp"
            custom:mTextSize="5sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Last played: 1/1/1"
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/preview"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

**Here is the activity_list.xml**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView">
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what do u mean by inflates same custom view over? Btw you might consider using ArrayAdapter instead of BaseAdapter. You wont need to override all those methods in adapter. You could use "getItem(position)" etc instead of maintaining your own list like you do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cells` field in your view is static. That means it applies to the entire class, not to each instance. Every time you initialize it with new cells, it changes the data for every preview view.

Drop the statics on `cells`, `cf`, and `mFileName` and it should start working.